# Continuos functions of compact support so that $\varphi_n(x)\to 1_K(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ a compact set. Build continuos functions of compact support $\varphi_n$ so that $0\leq \varphi_n\leq 1$, $\varphi_n|_K=1$ and $\varphi_n(x)\to 1_K(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @reuns...I try using that Urysohn Theorem but i not can not use this result adequately..

Comment: hint : $f_n(x) = \sup_{y} |f(x+y)|  e^{- n^2 y^2}$

Comment: @reuns..why $f_n\to 1_K(x)$?

Comment: Do you see the behavior of $f_n$ ?

Comment: @reuns..not I'm sorry..

Comment: try with $f(0) = 1$ and $ f(x)  =  0$ otherwise, then try with $f(x) = 1_{|x|\le 1}$.

Comment: Let $U_n =\{x:d(x,K)< \frac 1 n\}$. By Urysohn's Lemma there exists a continuous function $f_n$ taking values in [0,1] such that $f_n=1$ on K and it is 0 on the complement of $U_n$. If x is not in K then $d(x,K)>0$ so x is not in $U_n$ for n sufficiently large. This proves that $f_n$ converges pointwise to   $1_K (x)$.